# AOT Compilation Error Angular2

Tags: angular, aot

Hi I am having trouble compiling Angular2 project using AoT.

I referred to the Angular2 Cookbook [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#jit-dev-aot-prod).

But it's spitting out tons of errors. What am I doing wrong?

These are errors I am getting.

```
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:1380:101: Supplied parameters do not match any si
gnature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:1384:101: Supplied parameters do not match any si
gnature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:1388:101: Supplied parameters do not match any si
gnature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:1834:100: Supplied parameters do not match any si
gnature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:2155:52: Supplied parameters do not match any sig
nature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:2173:52: Supplied parameters do not match any sig
nature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-detail.component.ngfactory.ts:2241:48: Property 'toggled' does not exist on typ
e 'TeacherDetailComponent'.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-childviews/teacher-childview1.component.ngfactory.ts:256:100: Supplied paramete
rs do not match any signature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-childviews/teacher-childview1.component.ngfactory.ts:999:52: Supplied parameter
s do not match any signature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-childviews/teacher-childview3.component.ngfactory.ts:535:100: Supplied paramete
rs do not match any signature of call target.
Error at /Users/yoo/match-mAngular2/aot/src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/tea
cher-childviews/teacher-childview3.component.ngfactory.ts:733:52: Supplied parameter
s do not match any signature of call target.
```

Example of Error

```
const currVal_2_0_0:any = valUnwrapper.unwrap(this._pipe_slice_0.transform(valUnwrapper.unwrap(import3.castByValue(this._pipe_keyValues_2_1,(<View_TeacherChildviewThreeComponent0>this.parentView)._pipe_keyValues_2.transform)(this.context.$implicit.value['introduceInfo'])),12,13));
```

this is aot compiled file error and it seems that this is caused by this line in html template

```
        <div *ngFor="let epi of detail.value['introduceInfo']|keyValues|slice:12:13">
```

my teacehr detail component

```
@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'teacher-detail',
templateUrl: 'teacher-detail.component.html',
styleUrls: ['teacher-detail.component.css']
})

export class TeacherDetailComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;


currentUser: User;

private errorMessage: any;

teaInfo: any[];

constructor(
    private route: Router,
    private teaDetail: TeacherDetailService,
    private getQueryVal: TeacherDetailPassDataService,
    private requestQuery: TutorRequestComponent,
    private auth: AuthenticationService,
) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
}

getVal1() {
    return this.getQueryVal.passQueryVal1()
}

//area

getVal2() {
    return this.getQueryVal.passQueryVal2()
}

//grade

getVal3() {
    return this.getQueryVal.passQueryVal3()
}

//subject

getTeacherDetail(): void {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('gradeType', `${this.getVal2()}`)
    params.set('subjectType', `${this.getVal3()}`)
    params.set('district', `${this.getVal1()}`)

    this.teaDetail.getTeachersDetail(params)
        .subscribe
        (
        teaInfo => this.teaInfo = teaInfo,
        error => this.errorMessage = error
        )
}

public hideChildModal(): void {
    this.childModal.hide();
}

public isCollapsed: boolean = true;

public collapsed(event: any): void {
    console.log(event);
}

public expanded(event: any): void {
    console.log(event);
}


deepTeaInfo: Object = {};

getdeep_detailInfo(): void {
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('gradeType', `${this.getVal2()}`)
    params.set('subjectType', `${this.getVal3()}`)
    params.set('district', `${this.getVal1()}`)

    this.teaDetail.getDetailInfo(params)
        .subscribe
        (
        data => {
            this.deepTeaInfo = data;
            error => this.errorMessage = error
        })
}
val1: string;
val2: string;
val3: string;

passParams() {
    this.val1 = this.getVal2();
    this.val2 = this.getVal3();
    this.val3 = this.getVal1();
    this.requestQuery.passParams_request(this.val1, this.val2, this.val3);

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTeacherDetail();
    this.getVal1();
    this.getVal2();
    this.getVal3();
    this.getdeep_detailInfo();
    this.passParams();
}

onClick(charge, perWeek, perMinutes) {
    if (this.currentUser['data']['memberType'] == 'Parent') {
        this.route.navigate(['../request']);
        this.getQueryVal.setChargeValue(charge);
        this.getQueryVal.setLecutrePerWeek(perWeek);
        this.getQueryVal.setMinutesPerLecture(perMinutes);
    }
    else if (this.currentUser['data']['memberType'] == 'Student') {
        this.route.navigate(['../request']);
        this.getQueryVal.setChargeValue(charge);
        this.getQueryVal.setLecutrePerWeek(perWeek);
        this.getQueryVal.setMinutesPerLecture(perMinutes);
    }
    else if (this.currentUser['data']['memberType'] == 'Admin') {
        this.route.navigate(['../request']);
        this.getQueryVal.setChargeValue(charge);
        this.getQueryVal.setLecutrePerWeek(perWeek);
        this.getQueryVal.setMinutesPerLecture(perMinutes);
    }

    else if (this.currentUser['data']['memberType'] == 'Teacher') {
        this.childModal.show();
    }
}

showModal(){
     this.route.navigate(['../afterLogin']);
}

onLogout() {
    this.route.navigate(['../login']);
    this.auth.logout();
}
```

}

Thankyou

Comment: can you post the code and template of `src/app/pres/teacher-list/teacher-detail/teacher-detail.component`?

Comment: I've updated example error code above

Comment: Please post the entire `teacher-detail.component.ts`